# Project structure to deal with Path nuances in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, project-structure

I am developing a Python project and the current structure of the project looks like this:

```
myproject
__init.__py

contents
    - __init__.py
    - content1.py
    ...

configs
    - __init__.py
    - config.py
    ...
utils
    - __init__.py
    - helpers.py
    ..
app.py
```

Now If I want to access functions from `config.py` in the `configs` directory to `helpers.py`, I need to add these two lines in `helpers.py` at the top:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

Similary I have to add these lines in py files in each directory if I want to access them. This clearly doesn't feel the right way. Is there any other way to make the `absolute` and `relative` imports cleaner and easier? Any explanation on top of it would be very very helpful

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are many different ways to achieve what you are trying to do. Not all of them are clear and as easily maintainable (as you've concluded using `sys.path.append("..")`).

The best practice (IMO) is to import any function/class/etc that is needed elsewhere in your `myproject/__init__.py`.

For example:

**myproject/__init__.py**

```
from configs import my_config_func
```

Then...

**myproject/utils/helpers.py**

```
from .. import my_config_func
```